# Can we retrieve analytics on posts made through our IOS app to personal facebook accounts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-analytics

We have an iOS app used by brands at their events to capture branded photos of their fans, which their fans can then post to their personal Facebook pages.  Would any of the Facebook access tokens allow us to track all the engagement on those photos, including likes, shares, and tags? I had thought that the Facebook access token we use to post to personal Facebook pages didn't allow engagement with those posts to be tracked, however we are aware of a competitor providing this information so these analytics are now being requested by our clients too. Is there an access token that does allow this tracking?

Comment: To read a user’s personal posts/their photos, you need `user_posts`/`user_photos` permission.

Comment: Cheers CBroe, will give a go, and thanks for taking the time to respond.